# Adding words to Visual Studio intellisense autocomplete

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-2013, customization, intellisense

I wish to simply add more words that autocomplete will recognize.  We use some custom fields in our HTML (1000's of them) and I want autocomplete to pop up when we start typing one, with a drop down list of all that are available, narrowing them down and you type, just like the normal behavior.

The fact that we have so many might be an issue, but is there any way I can just add my own words that autocomplete will recognize?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx) should help.

You'll need to create a snippet file using [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms165394(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: From what I can tell, code snippets don't act as intellisense items, in that you either select them from the code snippet window, or you type the entire snippet name in then hit tab tab to get the whole snippet.  What I am wanting is to add words to the words that intellisense recognizes. When you start typing them, Intellisense recognizes the word from it's list, and a window opens up with all of the possible words you are typing, and lets you select one.  I want to add my own words to that list basically.  I am not trying to add an entire snippet.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I needed. To make the snippet visible in the autocomplete, I added <Shortcut> to <Header>.